# Regex for text outside <% %>

Tags: c#, regex

I need to parse a string like this:

`text0<%code0%>text1<%code1%><%%>text3`

into two arrays. Every chunk is optional, so it can be just `text` or `<%code%>` or an empty string. 
Taking out code is easy (if I'm not mistaken): `<%(.*?)%>`, but I need help with text as it has no such markers, unlike code.

Thanks!

Comment: To get an array of the texts you may just *split* by `<%.*?%>`. I'm not a `C#` dev so can't provide you with the right code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This very simple Regex will do :-) :-)
(this is irony... The regex is correct, but it's absolutely unreadable, and even an expert in regexes would probably need at least 10 minutes to comprehend it fully)

```
var rx = new Regex("((?<1>((?!<%).)+)|<%(?<2>((?!%>).)*)%>)*", RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);
var res2 = rx.Match("text0<%code0%>text1<%code1%><%%>text3");
string[] text = res2.Groups[1].Captures.Cast<Capture>().Select(p => p.Value).ToArray();
string[] escapes = res2.Groups[2].Captures.Cast<Capture>().Select(p => p.Value).ToArray();
```

remember that it requires the `RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture`.

The regex will capture in two Groups (1 and 2) the pieces of the string outside of `<% %>` and inside `<% %>`. Each group is composed of multiple `Capture`s.

The explanation:

```
( ... )* The outer layer. Any number of captures are possible... So any number of "outside" and "inside" are possible

(?<1>((?!<%).)+) The capturing group 1, for the "outside"

| alternatively

<% An uncaptured <%
(?<2>((?!%>).)*) The capturing group 2, for the "inside"
%> An uncaptured %>
```

The capturing group 1:

```
(?<1> ... ) The name of the group (1)
```

and inside:

```
((?!<%).)+ Any character that isn't a < followed by a % (at least one character)
```

The capturing group 2:

```
(?<2> ... ) The name of the group (2)
```

and inside:

```
((?!%>).)* Any character that isn't a < followed by a % (can be empty)
```

Note that this regex will break badly if there is an unclosed `<%`!!! The problem is fixable.

```
var rx = new Regex("((?<1>((?!<%).)+)|<%(?<2>((?!<%|%>).)*)%>|(?<3><%.*))*", RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);
```

and add

```
string[] errors = res2.Groups[3].Captures.Cast<Capture>().Select(p => p.Value).ToArray();
```

If `errors` isn't empty, there is an unclosed `<%`.

Now, if you want to have the captures sorted:

```
var captures = res2.Groups[1].Captures.Cast<Capture>().Select(p => new { Text = true, Index = p.Index, p.Value })
    .Concat(res2.Groups[2].Captures.Cast<Capture>().Select(p => new { Text = false, Index = p.Index, p.Value }))
    .OrderBy(p => p.Index)
    .ToArray();
```

every capture now has an `Index`, a `Text` that can be `true` for `Text` and `false` for  `Escape` and a `Value` that is the text of the `Capture`.

Answer (score 4):

Since regular expression matches must be contiguous (i.e. have no gaps) there is no single expression to match all text outside the tags. However, you can still do it if you combine regex with C#'s `string` facilities, like this:

```
var outside = string.Join("", Regex.Split(inputString, "<%.*?%>"));
```

If the inside of the tag may not contain percentage characters, you can optimize your regex to avoid [backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) by using this expression instead:

```
<%[^%]*%>
```

Comment: Or perhaps `<%((?!%>).)*%>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regex.Replace

```
var text = Regex.Replace(input, "<%.+?%>", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var input = "text0<%code0%>text1<%code1%><%%>text3";
        List<string>
            text = new List<string>(),
            code = new List<string>();
        var current = 0;
        Regex.Matches(input, @"<%.*?%>")
            .Cast<Match>()
            .ToList().ForEach(m =>
            {
                text.Add(input.Substring(current, m.Index - current));
                code.Add(m.Value);
                current = m.Index + m.Length;
                if(!m.NextMatch().Success)
                    text.Add(input.Substring(current, input.Length - current));
            });
    }
}
```